# How can I query a numpy array to find the minimum multiplication of the first two columns?

Tags: python, numpy

For example: `test_array = numpy.array([[10, 1], [2, 12], [3, 5]])` and I'd like to do something along the lines of `test_array.where( min(test_array[0] * test_array[1]) )` and have it return that same structure that `numpy.where` returns pointing to `[10, 1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you just want [numpy.argmin](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html)...

E.g.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[10, 1], [2, 12], [3, 5]])
multi_cols = x[:,0] * x[:,1]
print x[multi_cols.argmin()]
```